# How to assign a value to a set of 25 identical pixels in a raster layer?

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, raster-conversion, reclassify, resampling

*I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1*

I would like to create a new raster layer from an existing raster composed of 4 possible discrete values (MIN=0, MAX=4, VAL=0,1,2,3,4). This existing raster illustrate different categories of habitats, and I would like to group similar habitats together; so that when a square of 25 pixels (5x5 pixels) is composed of one and the same category, then a pixel of this new resolution is created and takes on the value of the detected category (1,2,3 or 4).
The other pixels that do not form a uniform 5x5 pixel square can either be excluded or retained from the new raster, it doesn't matter.

This image illustrates my point (except that I want a new resolution of 5 by 5 pixels):
[image]

Comment: You can't have mixed pixel sizes within a raster. You could achieve the equivalence if you  converted your data into polygons.

Comment: Con(focalSratistics(range)=0, raster). Convert result to (square) polygons. Complicated when you have 6 columns 5 rows of the same. BTW picture shows 3×3

Comment: Once transformed into polygone, I guess won't be able to identify the number of pixel within a square (I want 5x5 within a square).  It is okay if the output layer is composed only of the new pixels size.